# How to write regular expression to Validate phone number of format (0d)dddddddd in php using preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have been trying but not sure where i am wrong

```php
$validator = preg_match('/^\(\0\d{1})?\d{8})$/', $phone);

if($validator == true)
{
    echo "Valid phonenumber";
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid phonenumber";
}
```

Comment: I tried this still showing invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several  issues in `^\(\0\d{1})?\d{8})$`:

- `\0` matches the NUL (`\x00`) char
- `)?` here is trying to close an optional group, but there is no matching `(` before that position
- The `)` at the `$` anchor is also trying to close a group, but there is no matching `(` anywhere before.

I suggest just using

```php
$validator = preg_match('/^\(0\d\)\d{8}$/', $phone);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Nkczj/1). If the `(0d)` part is optional and can be missing, wrap that part with an optional non-capturing group, e.g.

```php
$validator = preg_match('/^(?:\(0\d\))?\d{8}$/', $phone);
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Nkczj/2).